# Need help to save/restore a string between activities

Tags: android, string, android-activity, save, restore

I'm learning Android and I didn't find an answer on the web. I want to save a string from an `EditText` on my `MainActivity` to restore it on my third `Activity` -> `Activity3`
I want this string to be displayed on a `TextView` of this `Activity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private EditText nomPrenom;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nomPrenom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nomPrenom);
 ...................}
```

in my activity_main.xml :

```
android:id="@+id/nomPrenom"
android:text="@string/nomPrenom"
```

and

```
public class Activity3 extends ListActivity {

private TextView yourName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity3);
    yourName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nomPrenom);
    yourName.setText("take the name of activity 1 here"); //<-- this line causes crash !!


..................}
```

here is activity3.xml

```
android:id="@+id/yourName"
android:text="@string/nomPrenom"
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Put your whole code of main activity.

Comment: can you post the error messages?

Comment: Try for Shared preferences..

Comment: Solved Thanks to everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your question is not so clear.. But as per given i think you need to fetch a data from edittext ( in main activity ) and then pass it to the third activity .

For This you need to use Intent to pass the data from one activity to other activity.

```
              Example  - 
              nomPrenom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nomPrenom);
              nomPrenom .getText.toString();

             Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity3 .class);
                    in.putExtra("value",nomPrenom .getText.toString()) ;
```

In Activity3 receive intent like this :-

```
                       String strValue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("value");
                       yourName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourName);
                       yourName.setText(strValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intent.putExtra("Your text here")` and pass it to other activities.

or you can take the string from `EditText` and make the string `Global`, `public` and `static` and then use it in any other class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with many ways ...

You can use shared preference so that you can access it from anywhere. But shared preference will retain your value after your application closed.

Another way pass your value with your activity intent when you are creating your activity like this: `intent.putExtra' and get value into your activity via`getExtra`

Another way you can define your variable at global place consider create one class too  hold such common variables and from there you can access those variable from anywhere.

All three ways can be changed according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In order to move from MainActivity to Activity3 write the following code

```
//get your edittext's text here
String text = nomPrenom.getText().toString();

//move to Activity3
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity3.class);
//pass the edit text value to Activity3
intent.putExtra("EditTextValue", text);
//start Activity3
startIntent(intent);
```

In Activity3, to get your edit text value do the following.

```
//get your edit text value here which is passed in MainActivity
String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("EditTextValue");
```

The variable "text" is the final output which you are looking for.